# Adding leading zeroes to an inputMask

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this inputMask for hours so it has the "HH:MM" format:

```
<p:inputMask mask="99:99"
    rendered="#{chamadoEditController.usuario.isColaborator}"
    styleClass="hourInput" maxlength="4"
    value="#{ticketEditController.durationMessage}"/>
```

I'm trying to make it so if someone inputs 15 the result would be 00:15. I wasn't even able to use inputStyle and set it to right, so I'm running out of options.
Any tips on how to do it without resorting to the back-end and and using ajax events or something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple javascript  with on the blur event might do the job

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timePicker/basicUsage.jsf

Comment: .. or the time only version of https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datePicker.xhtml